# How to set rootDir as process.cwd() + '/..'

Tags: jestjs

My application was setup as a mono repo. This is the structure:

```
\mono-repo
|--core
|--app1
|--app2
```

I run `jest` at app2. But I also want to run all tests from `core`. So here is my config

```
{
    rootDir: process.pwd() + '/..',
    roots: [ 'core', 'app2' ],
}
```

But it didn't work.
Could you give me any idea for this case?

Answer (score 0):

Using `process.cwd()` works for me. It looks like you're using a JSON file rather than a JS file, so it's not interpreting the command. You can also add `--showConfig` to the `jest` command for further debugging.